# determine whether the limit of a function contains a moving discontinuity is in $L^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm reading a paper A variational calculus for discontinuous solutions of systems of conservation laws from Alberto Bressan and Andrea Marson. I have a question at the very begining. Let $u^\epsilon(t,x)=\frac{(1+\epsilon)x}{1+(1+\epsilon)t}\cdot\chi_{[0,\sqrt{1+(1+\epsilon)t}]}(x)$, why the expression $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{u^\epsilon(t,\cdot)-u^0(t,\cdot)}{\epsilon}$ does not define any function in $\mathcal{L}^1$? I think for a given point x larger than $\sqrt{1+t}$, the value of the limit is 0.

Comment: To be in $\mathcal L^1$ requires adequately good behavior in all of the domain, not just one part of it.

Comment: I think the limit exists in the whole domain and bounded which is its absolutely continuous  part $\frac{x}{(1+t)^2}\chi_{[0,\sqrt{1+t}]}$. In the paper it says there's a singular part consists of a point mass located at $\sqrt{1+t}$. How does that come?